# Hidding toolbar for reports created using SSRS 2008 in CRM 2011

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, rdl

I have created report in SSRS 2008 and have attached them to the dashboard. The report is displaying fine, except for the fact that about 15-20 % of the space gets occupied by SSRS menu toolbar which has options for printing/zooming etc. Is there a way for me to minimize that tool bar?
I also have a parameter bar that I can hide. But it doesn't stay hidden by default. Is there a way for me to temporarily hide the parameter bar when the dashboard loads?
while googling i got this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx) but when i add that parameter to the report which is deployed i am getting CRM error. i am not very sure on the usage of the parameter which i am trying. i am very sure some sort of mistake i am doing. i am using the url in this way:

this is my url with parameter:
http://xxx3:5555/CCPFINCRM/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=filter&helpID=Test.rdl&id=%7bEFAB0D42-2165-E111-916B-90FBA631DAFB%7d&rc:Toolbar=false

The Error Message is as follows:
[image]

Comment: What is the CRM error message?

Comment: There will be a more detailed error message in your trace logs (see here for how to set tracing up: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490), can you post that?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Sample of working]

My solution involves several steps, mostly unsupported - but it works.

1. Clone the existing C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb\CRMReports\viewer\viewer.aspx to .\viewerNoToolbar.aspx
2. Update in viewerNoToolbar.aspx the following code to remove the Toolbar from SSRS :-

   ```
   function reportLoaded()
   {

   if (oFrame.readyState === "complete")
   {
       addToRecent();
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   function reportLoaded()
   {

   if (oFrame.readyState === "complete")
   {
       addToRecent();
       var frameDoc = oFrame.contentDocument || oFrame.contentWindow.document; 
       var reportViewerToolbar = frameDoc.getElementById("reportViewer_Toolbar");
       reportViewerToolbar.style.display = "none";
   }
   ```
3. Insert a DIV to hide the existing CRM toolbar and move the existing resultFrame IFrame out of the DIV

   ```
   </div>
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="100%">
   ```

   to

   ```
   </div>
   <div style="display: none">
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="100%">
   ```

   also close it off by changing the below from

   ```
        </table>
    </body>
   ```

   to (and remove the existing td block related to resultFrame)

   ```
           </table>
       </div>
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="100%">
           <tr style="height: 100%;">
               <td colspan="2" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px; border-width: 2px;
                   border-color: #000000">
                   <div id="divResultFrame">
                       <iframe name="resultFrame" id="resultFrame" src="/_static/blank.htm" style="border: 0px;
                           margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
                   </div>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </body>
   ```
4. Change your query to

   ```
   http://xxx3:5555/CCPFINCRM/crmreports/viewer/viewerNoToolBar.aspx?
   ```

   and don't worry about rc:Toolbar

Good luck 
Glenn