# CRM 2011 reporting with no toolbar post UR16

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I previously followed the instructions in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597242/hidding-toolbar-for-reports-created-using-ssrs-2008-in-crm-2011) to create a custom CRM report viewer page that did not have the CRM report toolbars (File menu and Edit Filter button).

It was working great until we installed UR16 for CRM. Now, it still works in Chrome or Firefox but no longer works in IE. It seems that in IE the page is getting redirected to a quirksviewer.aspx page (at least from what I can tell).

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Update to this. I spoke with Microsoft and they advised that the reason this no longer works is that they made a change to how reporting is handled for Internet Explorer to help with issues that cross browser support introduced for SSRS. Therefore, they no longer pass back a DOCTYPE element in their response data. This apparently forces IE into Quirks mode and a use of the new QuirksReportViewer.aspx page. They advised that they had found no way to restore this functionality to IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created two versions of the report viewer: one based on 'viewer/viewer.aspx' and one based on 'viewer/QuirksViewer.aspx'.  In a web resource I check the browser and direct IE to the quirks viewer.

But I found that IE8 was getting redirected to 'rsviewer/QuirksReportViewer.aspx'.  I fixed this by adding a 'meta' tag below the 'head' element to force the iframe out of compatibility mode.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<cnt:AppHeader id="crmHeader" runat="server" />
```

This only affects IE8, because in later versions, iframes are rendered in the same mode as the parent window.

Comment: The detecting IE and redirecting worked well. However, when I added the meta tag for IE8, IE9 no longer functioned as expected (the report was only showing a very small portion). I'm not hugely concerned with IE8 but am wondering why it is not working. Thanks for your help on this.